# What is the connector on lenovo ideapad miix board called?

Tags: connector, keyboard, laptop

The connector on board of keyboard of lenovo ideapad miix 300-10iby tablet.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Male part:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Female part:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a SWB 0800WRS-XX connector (2 Pin - 20 Pin Wire To Board Single Row Idc Connector Wafer 0.8mm Pitch).

http://www.cswb.cc/sale-8516545-2-pin-20-pin-wire-to-board-single-row-idc-connector-wafer-0-8mm-pitch.html

http://swb.tw/product/detail/id/9.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a 5-pin, 2.5mm pitch shrouded wafer connector.

From a quick google image search, this one looks like it might be compatible: http://www.wire-to-boardconnector.com/sale-7536275-jvt-2-5mm-pitch-wafer-for-pcb-board-connector-with-five-pins-in-white-color.html